# Accessing to Mariadb database with telnet from LAN

Tags: networking, mariadb

System is Debian 10 upgraded from Debian 9.
MariaDB version is mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB

1. Server machine running telnet command responds like this

```
telnet localhost 3306
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
b
5.5.5-10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1:)\uW5A(-?�D](M+/H_&>E|mysql_native_password
```

2. Client machine targeting the server responds like this

```
telnet 192.168.0.13 3306
Trying 192.168.0.13...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

3. What I have done so far is adding bind-address to `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf/50-server.cnf`

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

4. Giving permission to port 3306

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

5. There is no error message on `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Still cannot telnet my server on port 3306 any help would be appreciated thanks. My main purpose is connecting database with jdbc.

Comment: did you restart the database service, after you changed "bind-address" to "0.0.0.0"? what's output of "netstat -tlpn4"?

Comment: Yes, I restarted the service. The output is Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2285/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1124/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      670/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1124/master

Comment: Netstat shows that mysql is listening on all ips port 3306. So there may be two reasons I can think about: (1) your firewall may be more complex and in that case it may still prevent you from reaching port 3306 on ip 192.168.0.13, I would completely disable firewall and test it without; (2) make sure the ip 192.168.0.13 is the correct one and is still installed on the server, but not changed after reboot or dhcp/network/wifi/router restarts.

Comment: Thank you all of your efforts. I find out that my client firewall preventing connecting to remote host.